# What is the incidence of LTSs in the wild?

Tags: haskell

I have a [Haskell package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/crypto-enigma) that I'd like ([in order to simplify and stabilize my builds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52338228/656912)) to restrict to the most recent [Stackage LTS](https://www.stackage.org) versions, thus requiring anyone using older LTS, and thus older GHC, to use an older version of my package.

Currently my package supports [GHC 8.4 through 7.10](https://matrix.hackage.haskell.org/package/crypto-enigma) (via LTS 6.35, 7.24, 9.21, 9.6, 10.3, 11.22, and 12.10) but if I make this change I will be limited to 8.4 (or perhaps a bit earlier depending on what I target) and LTS after 10.3.

What is the incidence of LTS (or GHC version) usage in the wild? Are older versions widely used, or used in specific applications or contexts?

Comment: I doubt this is a good question for SO, but some people rely on pretty old versions of GHC. I think most users have reached 8.2, most of the rest have reached 8.0, and almost all have reached 7.10. A few still prefer to work with 7.6 or 7.8. People who are for some reason stuck with the version that shipped with their LTS OS distribution may go back further, but I personally refrain from caring at all about versions before 7.8 or much about versions before 8.0.